# Jquery addClass to navigation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having an issue trying to set a class to the active nav item. 
I need some help trying to figure out where i am going wrong. 
It is some what working but not correctly, it defaults to the menu item which has a sub menu and i can't see where i have gone wrong.

When clicking on say "contact us" for example - the href takes me to the contact page but the active class does not apply and remains on "Products"

What i want to happen is the active class applies to the item that is clicked and not stuck on "products"

Here is JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2yv92roL/

Thanks for help in advance!

Here is HTML:

```
<nav class="navigation">
 <ul class="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="{{URL('/')}}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="{{URL('ourphilosophy')}}">Our Philosophy</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Products</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="{{URL('/products')}}">Charbonnier Cookware</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{URL('/dinnerware')}}">Charbonnier Dinnerware</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{URL('/storageware')}}">Charbonnier Storageware</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="{{URL('/contact')}}">Contact us</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
/* define a fixed width for the entire menu */
.navigation {
  width: 150px;
}

/* reset our lists to remove bullet points and padding */
.mainmenu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* make ALL links (main and submenu) have padding and background color */
.mainmenu a {
  display: block;

  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;

}

/* add hover behaviour */
.mainmenu a:hover {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
}


/* when hovering over a .mainmenu item,
  display the submenu inside it.
  we're changing the submenu's max-height from 0 to 200px;
*/

.mainmenu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}

/*
  we now overwrite the background-color for .submenu links only.
 CSS reads down the page, so code at the bottom will overwrite the code at the top.
*/


/* hover behaviour for links inside .submenu */
.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #C5C5C5;
}

/* this is the initial state of all submenus.
  we set it to max-height: 0, and hide the overflowed content.
*/
.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
.navigation ul li .active {
        color: #0080A6;
    }
```

Here is my JQuery

```
$(function() {
     var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
     $(".navigation ul li a").each(function(){
          if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
          $(this).addClass("active");
     })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a couple of changes:

- Remove "$(this).attr("href") == ''" from your if condition, this is the reason your "Products" menu is getting the active class by default
- Add "$(".navigation ul li a").removeClass("active");" before your each to remove the active class from the previously selected menu
- Add "/" to your pgurl so that it matches the href attribute of your menus

Here is the updated code:

```
 $(function () {
        var pgurl = "/" + window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        $(".navigation ul li a").removeClass("active");
        $(".navigation ul li a")
            .each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl)
                    $(this).addClass("active");
            });
    });
```

Comment: In theory this should work, but what has happened is it has removed the "active" class from defaulting to "products" - however, on clicking a nav item and inspecting the DOM it doesn't seem to apply the active class. Can you do a jsfiddle? On click the page refreshes and i don't believe the active class stays on.

Comment: I wrote this to check if there is a match but it is not returning so i cant figure out where i could be going wrong.... 

 $(function() {
  var pgurl =  "/" + window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  var crnt = $(this).attr("href");
  $(".navigation ul li a").each(function(){

   if (crnt == pgurl)

    console.log("true");
  });
 });